# Manually Assigning Site Local IPv6 Multicast Address to DHCP Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6, dhcpv6

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Multicast_addresses, `ff05::1:3` is a site local multicast address for *All-dhcp-servers*. Based on this, when I add the DHCP role to a Windows Server 2012 R2, is it appropriate to assign `ff05::1:3` as one of the IPv6 addresses on the network interface?

Comment: No, that's not how multicast works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv4 DHCP is used with broadcast, but IPv6 doesn't have broadcast. Multicast addresses are group addresses to be used as destination addresses for groups to which hosts subscribe. You don't assign multicast addresses to a host interface. Your DHCP server would subscribe to the multicast group, as would all the DHCP servers.

[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.7)

> **2.7.  Multicast Addresses**
>
> An IPv6 multicast address is an identifier for a group of
> interfaces    (typically on different nodes).  An interface may belong
> to any    number of multicast groups.  Multicast addresses have the
> following    format:
>
> ```
> |   8    |  4 |  4 |                  112 bits                   |
> +------ -+----+----+---------------------------------------------+
> |11111111|flgs|scop|                  group ID                   |
> +--------+----+----+---------------------------------------------+
> ```
>
> binary 11111111 at the start of the address identifies the address
> as being a multicast address.